# Residual Spectrum of $(Tf)(x) = \int^x_0 f(y) dy + x f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory, integral-equations

Define the operator $T$ on $L^2[0,1]$ by $(Tf)(x) = \int^x_0 f(y) dy + x f(x)$. What is the residual spectrum of $T$ and is the residual spectrum the whole spectrum?

**My attempt:** Solving the eigenvalue problem: $\int^x_0 f(y) dy + x f(x) = \lambda f(x)$ by first differentiate to get $2 f(x) = f'(x) (\lambda - x)$. Away from $\lambda$ then $f(x) = \frac{C}{|\lambda - x|^2}$. Since $\lambda f(0) = 0$, if $\lambda \neq 0$ then $f(0) = 0$. But this gives $f(x) \equiv 0$, so not possible. On the other hand, if $\lambda = 0$, then $f(x) = \frac{C}{x^2}$ for $x \in (0,1]$. However, this is also not possible since $\int^x_0 f(y)dy$ is undefined. Thus the point spectrum of $T$ is empty.

$T$ is obviously bounded, so is $(T - \lambda)$. By the Bounded Inverse Theorem, $(T-\lambda)^{-1}$ is bounded, so the continuous spectrum is empty.

For the residual spectrum, first find the point spectrum of the adjoint and then apply the relation $\sigma_{res}(T) \subset \overline{\sigma_{pt}(T^*)}$, where the bar denotes complex conjugate. Exchanging the order of integration, the adjoint $T^*$ is defined by $(T^*f)(x) = \int^1_x f(y)dy + x f(x)$. Similar to the previous part, $\sigma_{pt}(T^*) = \{1\}$ since $1$ is the only possible eigenvalue. Since all linear bounded operator on complex Hilbert space has non-empty spectrum, $\sigma_{res}(T)$ must equal $\overline{\sigma_{pt}(T^*)} = \{1\}$.

**Questions:**

1/ Could someone please help me check this? I am very unsure of my work since I am quite new to operator theory.

2/ Can someone please give me a different example that has the whole spectrum being the residual spectrum aside from the left-shift operator?

3/ How should one generally approach these problems?

4/ Is it true that if $T$ is defined on $L^2(0,1)$ instead, then the residual spectrum is the entire spectrum?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the bounded inverse theorem applicable in the second paragraph?

Comment: Shouldn't it be applicable since $[0,1]$ is complete?

Comment: Bounded Inverse Theorem applies to bijective bounded operators between two Banach spaces. Assuming that $\lambda$ is in the continuous spectrum, $T - \lambda : L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ is injective but has dense range which is not all of $L^2[0, 1]$. So the range of $T-\lambda$ is not complete and the BIT is not applicable.

Comment: Also, for the second part, it seems that $\sigma_{\mathrm{pt}}(T^*) = (0, 1]$. Eigenvectors for $\lambda \in (0, 1]$ can be explicitly written as $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x < \lambda \\ 0, & x \geq \lambda \end{cases}. $$ It is not hard to check that other values of $\lambda$ are not eigenvalues of $T^*$.

Comment: Once again, thank you. For $T^*$, I have the eigenvalue problem to be $\int^1_x f(y)dy + xf(x) = \lambda f(x)$, which differentiated to $(\lambda - x)f'(x) = 0$, but I did not see to break down the cases. May I ask if there is a way to find the continuous spectrum in this case? It looks like I only have to consider the case of $\lambda = 0$ for the continuous spectrum.

Comment: I just realize that since the spectrum is closed, $\sigma_c$ has to be $\{0\}$.

Comment: I am not an expert of this topic, so I know little about general philosophy of finding $\sigma_c$. But in our case, once we establish that $\sigma(T) = [0, 1]$, then we can conclude $\sigma_{\text{c}}(T) = \{0\}$ since $\sigma_{\text{pt}}(T) = \varnothing$ and $\sigma_{\text{res}}(T) = \overline{\sigma_{\text{pt}}(T^*)} = (0, 1]$. I was able to show that $\sigma(T) \subset [0, 1]$ by adopting some iteration scheme, but I am not sure if this is approach is essential.

Comment: Let $f=\chi_{[0,\lambda]}$ for some $0 < \lambda \le 1$. Then $f \ne 0$. And $T^*f = \int_{x}^{1}\chi_{[0,\lambda]}dt+x\chi_{[0,\lambda]}=(\lambda-x)\chi_{[0,\lambda]}+x\chi_{[0,\lambda]}=\lambda\chi_{[0,\lambda]}=\lambda f$. Therefore $(0,1]\subset \sigma_p(T^*)$.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was very off for this problem.